# Errors While inserting hive output into mongodb table

Tags: mongodb, hive, insert

I have a data like company name company Id into two columns

ex: name 1212374
     name 12312231

I got the count from `hql` like `companyname`  count as (name 2,name 3,name 3)
while inserting into `mongo` table which I created giving errors like :

> hive> insert into table mongo_patentcount
>   select p.company as company , count(p.patentid) as patentcount from patentcount p group by p.company;

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-hduser/hive_2013-06-12_10-06-53_074_1114831142836879410/-mr-10001/274f6862-c5f9-4924-babf-64cbc828c038 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

Continuing ...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /home/hduser/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser/.staging/job_201306120937_0003/libjars/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException: File /home/hduser/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser/.staging/job_201306120937_0003/libjars/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)
)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

Comment: That one is resolved : now am getting error like  || Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)

Comment: If you resolved this problem, it would be great if you could post the answer for other people who run into the issue.  For the new problem, it's best to start a new question.

Comment: format namenode and restart all the daemons ..